# How can I get api data from the website, it shows me TypeError message

Tags: javascript

```
function getInfo() {
  fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // If there is any error you will catch them here
      console.log(error);
    });
}

const newPerson = document.getElementById('newQuote')
newPerson.addEventListener('click', getInfo); // new quote on button click
window.onload = getInfo; // new quote on page load
```

I wrote this code and in console I got the following message:
TypeError{}

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What is the full error message? What line triggers the error?

Comment: Best guess is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: The code doesnt reproduce the problem but it doesnt show in the console what I am expecting. I need to take data api form the file and instead of it I just receive TypeError{} message. Maybe my approach of solving this task is incorrect. I am newbie in this field.

Comment: Add ```async``` keyword before function. So, async ensures that the function returns a promise, and wraps non-promises in it.

Comment: @SadafNiknam — There's no point in doing that. There's no attempt to `await` anything or do anything with the return value (which is an event handler so nothing *can* be done with it)

Comment: Can you please share complete error trace. Your API call is perfectly fine

Comment: You code looks fine to me. Try once with dummy API. 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'.

Comment: @Devang — It runs fine with the API in the question too.

Comment: Why do you need window.onload = getInfo;  ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rqvowo here is screenshot what I get

Comment: please share your codesandbox link. thanks

Comment: @Devang I changed the link on ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') and I see that I can get the data! Thank you for help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `async` function as an event listener's function. What you should do is call the `async` function inside the listener's function.

```js
function getInfo() {
  fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // If there is any error you will catch them here
      console.log(error);
    });
}



const newPerson = document.getElementById('newQuote');

newPerson.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getInfo();
});

window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    getInfo();
});
```

```html
<button id="newQuote">New Quote</button>
```